# How to scroll a bootstrap modal with arrow keys up - down

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog

I tried this:

```
// this = modal
$(this).focus();
```

I tried tha above one as well as tried to trigger a click event on it but didn't work!

***EDIT***

This is the website i'm working on : "[website](http://ztrendynews.fr/)", you can launch the modal and see that it does not scroll with arrow keys.

But if you click on the modal it becomes scrollable, and that's why I tried to trigger the click event with jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the focus on the first `a` hyperlink element and see what that does:

```
$('.modal a:first-child').focus();
```